# Не получается запустить docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-2, dockerfile

При команде docker-compose up dbinit получаю следующее

```
docker-compose up dbinitStarting example_mysql_1 ... done
Starting example_dbinit_1 ... done
Attaching to example_dbinit_1
dbinit_1        | wait-for-it.sh: waiting for mysql:3306 without a timeout
dbinit_1        | wait-for-it.sh: mysql:3306 is available after 0 seconds
dbinit_1        | Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install 
dotnet SDK from:
dbinit_1        |   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? 
LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
example_dbinit_1 exited with code 145
```

В чем причина такого завершения?
файл docker-compose:

```
services:

  mysql:
    image: "mysql:8.0.0"
    volumes:
      - productdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecret
      - bind-address=0.0.0.0

  dbinit:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - INITDB=true
      - DBHOST=mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mvc:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
    environment:
      - DBHOST=mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  loadbalancer:
    image: dockercloud/haproxy:1.2.1
    ports: 
      - 3000:80
    links: 
      - mvc
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - frontend
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base

COPY dist /app

COPY node_modules/wait-for-it.sh/bin/wait-for-it /app/wait-for-it.sh

RUN chmod +x /app/wait-for-it.sh

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80/tcp

ENV WAITHOST=mysql WAITPORT=3306

ENTRYPOINT ./wait-for-it.sh $WAITHOST:$WAITPORT --timeout=0 \
    && exec dotnet ExampleApp.dll
```

Comment: это скачанный npm пакет

Comment: `exec dotnet ExampleApp.dll` вы из примера скопировали? он там существует?

Comment: точно, там должно быть example.dll

Comment: но проблему не решило

Comment: ошибка такая же после удаления или что?

Comment: Да. Такая точно как и была.

Comment: я скачал ваши примеры. добавил wait-for-it.sh `npm i wait-for-it.sh` 
у меня все стартануло успешно. 

попробуйте в пустой папке без dist и только сервисами mysql и dbinit сбилдить все и поднять

Comment: Без dist запустилось. Вы волшебник. Спасибо)

Comment: ERROR: for loadbalancer  Cannot start service loadbalancer: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint example_loadbalancer_1 (fac9c482151371e0cb368c5f187f830be1a2d7e6da9ca4e52686f7c4d87be3c3): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:4000:tcp:172.29.0.3:80: input/output error
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

все, кроме балансера запускается..

Comment: Надо было просто перезапустить докер. Вопрос решен.